# Secure web services using Symfony

Tags: web-services, symfony1, security

So I have Symfony project which is also in charge of database abstraction and the data layer. In short - all data requests should go through it.

Now I want to have external components that will want to query / update stuff in the database, using web service API that I expose.

Question: How do I make sure these web services are running inside a secure channel? I don't want unauthorized users to update my database, and I don't want eavesdroppers get hold of sensitive data. Is setting up client authentication using PKI a viable option? or is it overkill? What's the way this is tackled?

Thanks!
-DBG

Comment: Embed an authentication token into url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you if you have a limited number of service users, and know their ips, you can restict access to ceirtain urls by ips. 
Next, have a look at [Practical symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/15), where they embed an authentication token into the url.

Comment: Don't know the number / nature of my users - they could be spread all over the place with new ones joining etc. However the token thing looks like the right way to go, providing I put it all into an HTTPS tunnel - so thanks (again)!\